# c# serial port read byte array from serial port

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port

Im trying to read data from serial port and to compare it, but i cant get it working, data that i read isnt that i need to get and sometimes its incomplete
basicly what i want when data from serial port comes and if data data is equal to an array to write some data to serial port

```
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Serial1 = (SerialPort)sender;
        Serial1.DtrEnable = true;
        Serial1.RtsEnable = true;
        int bytes = Serial1.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        Serial1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        string buffer1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        newform(buffer1);
        showinwindow(buffer);

    }

    private void showinwindow(byte[] buffer)
    {
        byte[] array1 = { 0x03, 0x2F, 0x2C };
        bool a = array1.SequenceEqual(buffer);
        if (a == true)
        {
            byte[] upisipodatak = { 0x03, 0x20, 0x23 };
            serialPort1.Write(upisipodatak, 0, upisipodatak.Length);
        }
    }

    private void newform(string buffer1)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
                textBox1.AppendText(buffer1);
        }));
    }
```

Comment: I see only two problems. With my personal experience i found out, that it is not a good idea to use `DataReceivedHandler` to do more work that report to another thread that there are data. When I correctly remember, there was a problem with it *(sometimes)*. Perhaps it were missing data, but I'm not sure now. The second problem is that the received data must not be the full packet; You can sometimes get a single byte and then another two bytes. Both reads are incomplete and will not work in current state.

Comment: What method you use?

Comment: `SerialPort.DataReceived` can be fired for partial messages. Whatever communication form you use, the **only** way to get it right is to have an input fifo buffer which will store incoming data, and then dequeue from this fifo whenever you get a valid message.

Comment: I used standard method's like you, but I used a background worker to do call the read function and in my first case I used  events *(`AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`)* to synchronize the threads operations.

Comment: @Julo: If you have a single consumer, it should be simpler and more performant to use a `ConcurrentQueue<byte>`, there is no need for additional synchronization.

Comment: @Groo it was my first bigger work in C# where the previous solution was something similar to this and I had to change it *(too many errors on serial link)*. There was also a time-out response handling e.t.c. The events were used only because it does not consume CPU time on waiting and are released directly after the event is fired. Newer version use *(different applications)* have a different approach.

Comment: Do you have a way to know when you have the whole message?  Most protocols send a `<CR><LF>` at the end of the message.  If you had something like this, then in your `DataReceived` event, you just need to build your string until you see that, then you know you have the whole message and can do whatever you need to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that when you start the read, not all bytes are available so only a partial amount is returned. You might want to try a blocking read instead, along these lines:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to read <paramref name="count"/> bytes into <paramref name="buffer"/> starting at offset <paramref name="offset"/>.
/// If any individual port read times out, a <see cref="TimeoutException"/> will be thrown.
/// </summary>

public void BlockingRead(SerialPort port, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    while (count > 0)
    {
        // SerialPort.Read() blocks until at least one byte has been read, or SerialPort.ReadTimeout milliseconds
        // have elapsed. If a timeout occurs a TimeoutException will be thrown.
        // Because SerialPort.Read() blocks until some data is available this is not a busy loop,
        // and we do NOT need to issue any calls to Thread.Sleep().

        int bytesRead = port.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        offset += bytesRead;
        count -= bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception on timeout (and you can configure the timeout for the serial port using [`SerialPort.ReadTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx).)

However, be aware that the .Net SerialPort implementation has some flaws. [See this article for details](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

In particular, `SerialPort.Read()` is a blocking call, which you would normally want to avoid, but doing so will mean that you will have to do some reading up yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the article link. But it seems the article does not describe the most problematic part of `SerialPort`. When the serial port 'is removed' and the port was opened, the CPU load rises to 100 % and memory consumption rises outside all bounds. The issue was in .NET Framework 2.0 and was fixed for local serial ports in version 3.5, but it still remains when you use remote desktop serial ports and the remote desktop connection is interrupted. The solution is to detect this problem and kill the thread *(or something similar)*. It is already a few years since I solved this problem.

Comment: @julo You appear to be describing an issue that you had which is not the same as the one the OP has.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for me like 90 of 100 times just removed

```
Serial1.DtrEnable = true;
Serial1.RtsEnable = true;
```